# Performance in Linear search not improving when used with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, arrays, search, multiprocessing

I tried to parallelize linear search in python using a multiprocessing module and created two processes with it. However, it seems to take even more time than the unparalleled process. The code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import random
from time import sleep, time
#from threading import Thread



def linearsearch(arr,search_var):
  count=0
  index_list=[]

  for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i]==search_var:
      count+=1
      index_list.append(i)
        


def linearsearch_p1(arr,search_var):
  count=0
  index_list=[]

  for i in range(0,round(len(arr)/2)):
    if arr[i]==search_var:
      count+=1
      index_list.append(i)
        

        
def linearsearch_p2(arr,search_var):
  count=0
  index_list=[]

  for i in range(round(len(arr)/2),len(arr)):
    if arr[i]==search_var:
      count+=1
      index_list.append(i)

number_to_search=5

input_array=[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(10000)]
array_len=len(input_array)
start=time()

#print(input_array)
linearsearch(input_array,number_to_search) 

finish=time()

print(f'Time taken by Single Process Linear Search {finish-start: .2f} second(s) to finish')

start_time = time()

t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p1, args=(input_array,number_to_search))
t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p2, args=(input_array,number_to_search))


t1.start()
t2.start()


t1.join()
t2.join()

end_time = time()

print(f'It took {end_time- start_time: 0.2f} second(s) to complete.')
```

The output of the above code on my PC is:

**Time taken by Single Process Linear Search  0.00 second(s) to finish.

It took  0.17 second(s) to complete.**

So, 0.17 is the time using multiprocessing module which is more than 0.00 secs of the single process time. But it should not be. Can anyone explain this kind of behavior?

Comment: Try with a much larger array (10-100 million elements or so). The time it takes to go through 10000 elements is insignificant compared to the time it takes to initialize a new thread and everything.

Comment: multiprocessing will run multiple functions calls in parallel, but isn't designed to break a single function call into parallel processes.  The difference between the two is the overhead created by the multiprocessing library.  If you had a million of these you needed to run, and the function itself took longer to execute - then you would see the benefits.

Comment: @AddisonSchmidt , already tried, multiprocessing gets even more time consuming.

Comment: @Chris, can you pls clarify your comment with some example?

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I would code your benchmark. I have purposely not included the time to create the child processes in the total multiprocessing time and am only passing half the list to each process to demonstrate that even by doing that and searching larger lists, the multiprocessing version will be less performant than a simple loop. The reason for this is the great overhead in passing the list data to the child processes cannot be overcome by performing the searches in parallel with such a trivial worker function, `linearsearch_p2`:

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
from time import time

NUMBER_TO_SEARCH = 5
ARRAY_LEN = 1_000_000
HALF_ARRAY_LEN = ARRAY_LEN // 2

def linearsearch(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in range(ARRAY_LEN):
        if arr[i] == NUMBER_TO_SEARCH:
            count += 1
    return count

def linearsearch_p2(arr, result_queue):
    count = 0
    for i in range(HALF_ARRAY_LEN):
        if arr[i] == NUMBER_TO_SEARCH:
            count += 1
    result_queue.put(count)


def main():
    input_array=[random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(ARRAY_LEN)]

    start = time()
    count = linearsearch(input_array)
    finish = time()
    print(f'Count = {count}, Time taken by Single Process Linear Search {finish-start: .2f} second(s) to finish')

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p2, args=(input_array[0:HALF_ARRAY_LEN], result_queue))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p2, args=(input_array[HALF_ARRAY_LEN:ARRAY_LEN], result_queue))
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    start_time = time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    count = result_queue.get() + result_queue.get()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end_time = time()
    print(f'Count = {count}, It took {end_time- start_time: 0.2f} second(s) to complete.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
ount = 99757, Time taken by Single Process Linear Search  0.05 second(s) to finish
Count = 99757, It took  0.24 second(s) to complete.
```

But if the cost to compare elements were much higher so that the search functions required significantly more CPU, then multiprocessing becomes more performant. Here I have made the searching more expensive by repeating the searching `REPEAT` times:

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
from time import time

NUMBER_TO_SEARCH = 5
ARRAY_LEN = 1_000_000
HALF_ARRAY_LEN = ARRAY_LEN // 2
REPEAT = 50

def linearsearch(arr):
    for _ in range(REPEAT):
        count = 0
        for i in range(ARRAY_LEN):
            if arr[i] == NUMBER_TO_SEARCH:
                count += 1
    return count

def linearsearch_p2(arr, result_queue):
    for _ in range(REPEAT):
        count = 0
        for i in range(HALF_ARRAY_LEN):
            if arr[i] == NUMBER_TO_SEARCH:
                count += 1
    result_queue.put(count)


def main():
    input_array=[random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(ARRAY_LEN)]

    start = time()
    count = linearsearch(input_array)
    finish = time()
    print(f'Count = {count}, Time taken by Single Process Linear Search {finish-start: .2f} second(s) to finish')

    start_time = time()
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p2, args=(input_array[0:HALF_ARRAY_LEN], result_queue))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=linearsearch_p2, args=(input_array[HALF_ARRAY_LEN:ARRAY_LEN], result_queue))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    count = result_queue.get() + result_queue.get()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end_time = time()
    print(f'Count = {count}, It took {end_time- start_time: 0.2f} second(s) to complete.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Count = 99726, Time taken by Single Process Linear Search  2.96 second(s) to finish
Count = 99726, It took  2.08 second(s) to complete.
```